# How to setup LinqToEntitiesDomainService in Web.Config?

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I inherited a project with a service that derives from LinqToEntitiesDomainService. I've got a jsonp binding defined in web.config. How do I associate my LinqToEntitiesDomainService service with that binding?

When I define the service in the services section, both service and contract show as invalid. Does the LinqToEntitiesDomainServives work differently in regards to assigning a binding?

Comment: This is part of WCF RIA services, its a special type of WCF service for use with silverlight apps, it doesn't use JSON or XML, it uses some kind of binary serialisation. I don't think you can bind it to a standard WCF endpoint.

Comment: I was wrong, more info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707373%28v=vs.91%29.aspx